# Retrieving value from angularjs http post response in case of ASP.Net web API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm using ASP.Net web api along with AngularJS to build a SPA. At this step I'm trying to retrieve a value from the response of a http post request, actually the saved id of last entry. I am getting the appropriate response but can't figure out the exact format of code to retrieve the value of the id from the response. I just need to know the exact format, I tried response.value.data.id but it didn't work for me. I also tried JSON.stringify(response) which doesn't provide the value object in the string.

[image]

Here's the function -

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var Patient = {
        name: $scope.PatientName,
        age: $scope.PatientAge,
        contact: $scope.PatientContact,
        address: $scope.PatientAddress
    };
    var response = patientService.post(Patient);
    console.log(response);
    //$location.path('/patient/' + $scope.PatientContact);
}
```

And here's the http post request -

```
this.post = function (Patient) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/api/PatientsAPI",
        data: Patient
    });
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $http function is returning a promise instead of the actual data.

So instead of `var response = patientService.post(Patient);`

You can use

```
var id;
patientService.post(Patient).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  id = response.value.data.id; // might not be correct, adjust according to response;
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, just needed to use response.data.id instead of response.value.data.id, thanks a lot for the answer